# How to craft the xcm call from a parachain to the relay chain's registrar.swap extrinsic (for extending the parachain lease period)?

Tags: parachain, auctions, lease

Is there some documentation explaining how to craft the xcm call from a parachain to the relay chain's registrar.swap extrinsic (in the context of extending the parachain lease period)?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can find the answers in the Polkadot wiki and reference another parachain's team's governance proposal and XCM call parameters for guidance:

- **Polkadot wiki:** https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-auction#lease-extension-with-overlapping-slots
- **Moonbeam's example:** https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/referenda/139
- **The equivalent call on SubScan:** https://polkadot.subscan.io/referenda_v2/139